# how to fetch element with == $0 using Selenium webDriver

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to identify the Element with "Tick" mark against it. But the problem is that whether the mark is visible in the row or not, all the HTML attributes of the element are same. 
I need to identify the row with tick mark against it.
I am not sure what is causing it to disapper for undesired rows. Only difference I could find between visible tick mark and invisible is "**== $0**". Could anyone please help me with this?

[For the preferred email type "Tick" mark is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k95rh.jpg)

Comment: add the html code in question

Comment: IMO, you are mixing up `"Tick" mark` with `"== $0"`. Those two are separate entities all together. What is your exact question? Thanks